# The easiest way to check if all values of std::map are equal

Tags: stl, stdmap

What is the easiest way to check if values of some std::map are equal for all the keys, without (at least, visible) iterating over all of them? Can it be done in one operation?

Answer (score 4):

Get the value of the first element and then check the remaining ones using [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with a custom predicate. Something like:

```
if (!mp.empty()) {
    int val = mp.begin()->second;
    result = std::all_of(std::next(mp.begin()), mp.end(), 
                         [val](typename <insert map type>::const_reference t){ return t->second == val; });
}
```

Comment: std::all_of is C++11 by the way

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) and then verify that the distance between the begin iterator of the map and the end iterator returned by [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) is 1.

Comment: It is not an efficient solution because `std::unique` modifies the map.

Comment: @Andrey: True, however the OP asked for the 'easiest' way (doable in 'one operation'); I assumed that a `std::unique` solution would be short but maybe it actually isn't (I started getting doubts that `std::unique` can be used with `std::map` iterators since the iterator points to a pair with a `const` first field).

Answer (score 0):

This function may suit your needs

```
template <typename Map>
bool IsUnique(const Map& i_map)
  {
  return std::count_if(i_map.cbegin(), i_map.cend(), 
      [&i_map] (typename Map::const_reference v)
      { 
      return v.second == i_map.cbegin()->second; 
      }) == i_map.size();
  }
```

Comment: It is not an efficient solution because `count_if` won't terminate early (the function could return as soon as it found the first mismatch). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it without the if statement checking for an empty map with std::all_of if you can live with one redundant comparison:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
bool all_equal(std::map<Key, Value> const& map)
{
    // the lambda will only get called when the map is not empty
    // so we can safely access begin()->second
    auto const cmpWithFirst = [&](std::pair<Key,Value> const& i)
    {
        return map.begin()->second == i->second;
    };

    return std::all_of(map.begin(), map.end(), cmpWithFirst);
}
```

This compares all elements to the first element if there are any, including the comparison of the first one against the first element.